# how to detect swiping, pinch-in and pinch-our zooming gesture of ImageView?

Tags: android

I have an imageView in my activity and I want to detect the left and right swiping and pinch-in and pinch-out zooming for that image?
Is there any way to do that without using a third party library?

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried something?

Comment: There are ways to do it without 3rd party libs but honestly, the amount of work it takes, doesn't pay off.

Comment: `without using a third party library` yes there is, but what is the difference between you using 3rd-party library, or you using code from the answer here? Both will result you in using somebody else's solution, not your one. Any code written by someone else, and used by you is a **3rd-party library** in fact.

Comment: I have tried to use SimpleOnGestureListener to listen to the events but seems I can only detect swiping, not pinching. May be I don't know how to do that with SimpleOnGestureListener. That's why I'd like to know whether there are other class that I can use to detect both swiping and pinching ? Thanks Guys !

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to achieve it by making a `Custom Java Class` to do that or either get to know that how the third party libraries are doing these things.

So, I don't know how much **features** you are looking for.
I can just provide you a simple class that I have used somewhere in my project to achieve same things like this.

May this will surely help you.

check this class https://gist.github.com/abhi08singh/26e2c141c142dd180de84d5b73cd620e